# How to automate dynamic token generated by a URL for Rest API in SOAPUI?

Tags: rest, groovy, automation, token, soapui

For my project
I have created test cases in SOAPUI for Rest project. 
I have to pass token in header for each test steps that I have added in the test cases.

Also the token validity only for 1 hour. So every hour I have to enter the token in the headers.

I want to know is there any way automate this token entry and generation  dynamically ?

For now what I am doing is getting token every time by refreshing the URL in every 1 hour and putting it manually in header of every test case and test steps.

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like the following Groovy script as the first test step of your test case. This gets your authorisation token from whatever service you use and sets it in your request header:

```
def authorisationToken = // Retrieve a new token from your authorisation service

// Get the headers for the request
def restRequest = testRunner.testCase.getTestStepByName('REST request')
def headers = restRequest.httpRequest.requestHeaders

// Set the token as a header. Remove it first in case it already exists
headers.remove("Authorisation")   // Or whatever your header is called
headers.put("Authorisation", authorisationToken)
restRequest.httpRequest.requestHeaders = headers
```

If you need to, you could also create a custom property at, say, the test suite level, then set this property after you retrieve it:

```
testRunner.testCase.testSuite.project.setPropertyValue("Authorization", authorisationToken)
```

Then, you could use it anywhere you need with `${#TestSuite#authorisationToken}`